# Pointer to function won't compile

Tags: c++

```
//mediafactory.h

class MediaFactory{
public:
        typedef Media* (*funPointer)();
    funPointer somePointer;
}

//mediafactory.cpp

Media* MediaFactory::returnMedia(){

}
```

when I try to do

```
somePointer = returnMedia;
```

I get this error:

```
1   IntelliSense: a value of type "Media *(MediaFactory::*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "MediaFactory::funPointer"   c:\Users\...\mediafactory.cpp   37
```

However, if i change the function to the code below, it will compile and work

```
Media* returnMedia(){   //without scope

}
```

Comment: You seem to be deeply confused about the difference between global ("ordinary") functions, and *member functions* in classes. The latter have a hidden `this` argument, which is why the two are not compatible.

Comment: You need to make `MediaFactory::returnMedia` a static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaFactory::returnMedia()` is a *non-static member function*, and can only be called via an instance of `MediaFactory`.

`typedef Media* (*funPointer)();` defines a pointer to a *static* or *non-member* function, which is called without any object. It's therefore a different type, incompatible with a pointer to a member function.

If you don't need it to point to a member function, then make `returnMedia()` either static or a non-member (as you note in at the end of the question).

If you do need it to point to a member function, then you need a pointer-to-member:

```
typedef Media* (MediaFactory::*funPointer)();
```

which can be set to point to a member function:

```
somePointer = &MediaFactory::returnMedia;
```

and can be called on a factory object:

```
Media * media = (someFactory.*somePointer)();
```

Alternatively, you might want to bind the function pointer to an object when you set the pointer, rather than when you use it. In this case, you could use `std::function` (or `boost::function` if you're stuck with an outdated compiler) to store an arbitrary callable object:

```
typedef std::function<Media*()> function;
function someFunction;

someFunction = std::bind(&MediaFactory::returnMedia, &someFactory);

Media * media = someFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks. Took me hours but your answrr cleared up 99% of the confusion. Why is fun pointer a static pointer?  If I do int random inside the class then it should be a member variable no?

Comment: @ThuanTrinh: Yes, the pointer should be a member. Who said anything about it being static?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a method of a class to a global function pointer without an instance of this class.